# Can i search and get files from search bar google drive using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

***Can I search*** and get files from search bar google drive using google script ?

I want to search using google script into drive search bar and select the result from search how do i do that ?

Tried this:

```
var types = [MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, MimeType.BMP,
             MimeType.CSS , MimeType.CSV,MimeType.FOLDER,MimeType.GIF,
             MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT,MimeType.GOOGLE_DRAWINGS,
             MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS,MimeType.GOOGLE_SITES,
             MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES,MimeType.HTML,MimeType.JAVASCRIPT,
             MimeType.JPEG,MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL,
             MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY,MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT,
             MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT_LEGACY,MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD,
             MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD_LEGACY,MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_GRAPHICS,
             MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_PRESENTATION,
             MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_SPREADSHEET,MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_TEXT,
             MimeType.PDF,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT,MimeType.PNG,
             MimeType.RTF,MimeType.SVG,MimeType.ZIP]
```

I don't want to work with each type by it's own. Can't we get help from google API and use their magnificent search bar available to us on drive ?

Comment: Hello Tony, Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've reformatted your post. You can use the formatting buttons above the editor for quotes and code. You can also go back and edit your posts at any time.

Comment: What do you mean by "search and get files"? To open them in your browser? To export them to your local disk? If the second, then sure. Use a standalone Apps Script project to create a webapp, and in the project use `Drive` advanced service or native `DriveApp`, coupled with `ContentService`. That's a lot of filetypes so make sure you handle long execution times.

Comment: i am creating an app that i want to search for a word and get all results , containing this search , from title to contained , the results that i get when i search in drive , i want to search and get them using google script , get them into an array